# Returing image from JSP page not working?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, weblogic11g

i am using [this method](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0360__JSP/ReturnanImageFromJSPPage.htm)

```
<IMG SRC="basic.jsp">
```

for showing image in img tag this method work fine in tomcat but in weblogic server it is giving following error :

```
   The image “view-source:https://10.189.65.201:7003/UploadImg/getImage.jsp” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

i know if i use Servlet with doGet() method instead a JSP psge it will work fine but why it is not working in this way is there any settings issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any whitespace outside `<% ... %>` in the JSP file will also be printed and sent to the HTTP response.

So if you have e.g.

```
<% ... %>
<% ... %>
<% ... %>
```

then effectively 2 newlines will also be sent to the reponse. This corrupts the binary format of the image.

You'd basically need to replace it by

```
<% ... %><% 
   ... %><% 
   ... %>
```

to prevent those newlines being printed to the response (and make sure that there's no trailing newline, either).

Or, better, just use a servlet. JSP is meant to generate text based content like HTML, not binary based content like images. Something with using the right tool for the job.